# How do I get the value of a form dropdown from bootstrap 4 when immediatly selected using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm using a form dropdown from bootstrap 4. How do I get the selected value when it's immediately selected using PHP?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="dropFields">Field:</label>
    <select class="field-select form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="dropFields">
        <option value="one"> 1 </option>
        <option value="two"> 2 </option>
        <option value="three"> 3 </option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

I want to be able to get the value "one" "two" or "three" when it's immediately selected. So that if the value is "three" a new dropdown will appear.

Comment: You can't do that with PHP, you need Javascript.

Comment: You can use Ajax for send form to the server if you won't refresh the page. Did you try to use Ajax?

Comment: How can I do it with Javascript then?

Comment: @MostafaKalantariFard I haven't tried that, how could i do that? Should it be an onClick or onChange event"

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the result without reloading the page unless you use Ajax. So please try using this code to get what you want.

Your HTML source will be:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dropFields">Field:</label>
    <select class="field-select form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="dropFields" onchange="showResult(this.value)">
        <option value="one"> 1 </option>
        <option value="two"> 2 </option>
        <option value="three"> 3 </option>
    </select>
</div>

<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtResult"></span></p>
```

And your Javascript(Ajax) code will be:

```js
function showResult(str) {
        var xhttp;
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                this.responseText
                document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q="+str, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

Also. you should create a new PHP with name "gethint.php" (for this example) and add this code:

```html
<?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "one";
$a[] = "two";
$a[] = "three";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```